# Why is my JTextArea append not working

Tags: java, swing

Today, I wanted to pick up java, by making something to list all files in a directory (so that I can easily see what cards I miss in a digital card collection).
I got the file walker to work, however, it doesn't append the file names to the JTextArea I made.

I have this code:

```
package finlaydag33k.swing.gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    static JTextArea filePanel = new JTextArea();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Gui frame = new Gui();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    try(Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/finlay/Pictures"))) {
                        paths.forEach(filePath -> {
                            if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                                //System.out.println(filePath);
                            filePanel.append("Hii");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Gui() {
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][grow]", "[][grow]"));

        JTextArea filePanel =  new JTextArea();
        contentPane.add(filePanel, "cell 1 1,grow");
    }

}
```

On `line 34`, the issue seems to happen (I just add the `hii` as a placeholder there so I can figure out the issue).
I don't get any error (only some warning saying 
`The serializable class Gui does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long`, but this shouldn't cause it right?).
The GUI just loads up with the textArea empty.
I hope somebody will be able to help me :)

Please forgive me for any cringe that you might get when reading the code :)
Cheers!

Comment: Post the code, not a link.

Comment: @bradimus beat me to it :)

Comment: No, don't post the code.  Post a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Are there any files in the path you want to check? Did you debug your code?

Comment: You have two `JTextArea` objects, one called `FilePanel`, the other one `filePanel` . Get rid of one of them (preferably of `FilePanel`, which doesn't follow naming conventions) .

Comment: Yes, there are files in there when uncommenting the `System.out.println(filePath);` it shows all the files in the console.

Comment: I've renamed the `FilePanel` to `filePanel`, but it doesn't fix the issue :\

Comment: @FinlayRoelofs : Remove the line `JTextArea filePanel =  new JTextArea();` from `Gui()`, because this variable is local to the constructor and is distinct from your other `JTextArea` with the same name .

Comment: Not what you asked, but `paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(filePanel.append("Hii"));` is cleaner.

Comment: *"Today, I wanted to pick up java,.."* Hmm.. and you decided to start with GUIs (not easy in any language, and harder to make cross platform GUIs), and using custom layouts. Are you familiar with the term 'biting off more than you can chew'? See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two instance with the same name but in different scope :

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

    static JTextArea filePanel = new JTextArea();
```

And in the constructor :

```
public Gui() {
    ...
    JTextArea filePanel =  new JTextArea();
```

Which mean that you are adding the one declared in the constructor to the frame but are appending the static one in the main. Not the same instance at all.

Remove the static (because this doesn't make sense)

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

     JTextArea filePanel;
```

Remove the second declaration, to initiliaze the variable in the constructor

```
public Gui() {
        ...
        filePanel =  new JTextArea();
```

and use the variable instance in the main to access it

```
frane.filePanel.append("Hii");
```

---

For more explanation, search about shadowing field in Java. This is simply what you are doing. You hide an variable by declaring the same variable in a different scope.

Comment: This worked! also, thanks for the detailed information on what exactly I was doing, and how I should do it instead :D